# Is there a FileReader equivalent for a URL in Java?

Tags: java, url

Consider the following.

```
val br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName))
```

But instead of a file, I want to read a file directly from the web, that is, from ftp or http. So, what would be the equivalent for reading from a URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **[URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)**.

Here's an example from Java documentation : [Reading from and Writing to a URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use java.io.InputStream

import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*;

```
public class URLConnectionReader { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    } 
}
```

for more info see [Reading Directly from a URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)